# I cannot get 'autobiographer' badge

Tags: support, badges

I edited 'about me' section, but cannot get 'autobiographer' bronze badge.

What is the problem?

Comment: Many badges, including the autobiographer badge, are awarded in batches, so it can be a few minutes to a few hours before they appear: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352822/347908